# how to perform xslt transformation for input request in adapter

Tags: xslt, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server

i have created a `XSLT` for the `WL.Server.invokeHttp` which gets the data from the backend server in XML format and performing transformation successfully. this adapter is used to get the data from backend server.

but while sending data to server in XML , as i am getting data in adapter as JSON ,  i need to transform it into XML using XSLT.

is there any provision in ibm worklight adapters that i can perform XSLT transformation for input request just the way i can do it easily while getting response from backend server.

Here i am explaining the return data ( i.e. response)

for example,

if i want to fetch data for all employees , i will invoke an adapter i.e. `getEmpDetails` which is returning data in XML , but i don't want to display all the fields those are returning from backend server , so i am using XSLT to filter the specific data and my mobile app is consuming it in JSON so i am transforming into JSON format also.

**Data from Server**

```
<Employee>
    <EmpName>Jhon Methew</EmpName>
    <EmpId>1234</EmpId>
    <EmpDepartment>Accounts</EmpDepartment>
</Employee>
<Employee>
    <EmpName>James</EmpName>
    <EmpId>4434</EmpId>
    <EmpDepartment>Sales</EmpDepartment>        
</Employee>
<Employee>
    <EmpName>Anna</EmpName>
    <EmpId>3344</EmpId>
    <EmpDepartment>Business Development</EmpDepartment>
</Employee>
```

After transformation by assigning XSLT in adapter i am getting following data

```
"array":{

      "employee":[{

         "empname":"John Methew",
         "empdept":"Accounts"


       },{

         "empname":"Anna",
         "empdept":"Business Development"


       }],

}
```

now if i want to add a new employee via `createEmp` adatper then i need to pass the input request in JSON format from mobile to create a new employee, and my adapter needs to transfrom this request into XML ( here, i want an XSLT filter the way i am heaving in `getEmpDetails` adapter ).

**input request to create employee**

```
"employee":{

             "empname":"Rahul",
             "empdept":"Softwares",
             "empid":"4233",
             "emppay":"20k"


           }
```

adapter will accept the response and need to convert above JSON input request to XML , so i was asking is there any provision in worklight to transform incoming request ?

```
<Employee>
        <EmpName>Rahul</EmpName>
        <EmpId>4233</EmpId>
        <EmpDepartment>Softwares</EmpDepartment>
        <EmpPayment>20K</EmpPayment>
</Employee>
```

Comment: Not familiar with Worklight, but XLST is usually not used to transform JSON to XML, not even the other way round. How about using a tool or library that understands JSON?

Comment: well, i want to map few data fields from JSON to XML that's why i am using it and worklight automatically does the transformation automatically for output response.

Comment: I am being told (by the developers) that - no, there is no such available provisioning in Worklight.

Comment: @Hunt, can you define what do you mean "input request"? Can you elaborate on what you are sending and what you are expecting on both ends (client and backend)?

Comment: @IdanAdar i have edited my question can you please look over it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT is not converting XML to JSON. XSLT transforms XML into another XML not JSON.

Once your adapter has retrieved XML from a backend the WL Server infrastructure will automcatically convert it to JSON. In case you have XSLT defined the original XML retrieved from a backend will first be translated into new XML according to XSLT and after that the new XML will be converted to JSON.

There's no out-of-the-box APIs that can convert JSON object to XML string in WL adapters. You can follow two different approaches here

1. Use 3rd party Java/JavaScript library to convert JSON to XML, e.g. https://code.google.com/p/x2js/ or  http://www.json.org/java/. You can read more about using Java in adapters here http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html , search for "Using java in adapters"
2. Manually create your XML templates and populate them with values from JSON. See page 18+ of http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/04_02_HTTP_adapter_-_Communicating_with_HTTP_back-end_systems.pdf. Use {myJsonObject.propertyName} to inject values to XML.

Comment: Incorrect.
WL or MFP.server.Invoke(options): options can take the name of the xsl file that can be used in order to parse an xml/soap response into json by simply specifing <xsl:output method="text"/> after the stylesheet declaration.
It is then returned as json by the responseJSON field of the response itself.
Read More:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-server/html/MFP.Server.html#MFP.Server.invokeHttp