# MobileFirst Adapter XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

As far as I have understood in MobileFirst Adapter Transformation using XSL.

We are outputting the data as text meaning converting the XML to text and forwarding via Adapter.

My Scenario

1. I need to parse the XML only when the XML contains some relevant data which I require like `Catalog` array in below XML not equal to `0`.
2. If the relevant data is not there I don't want my XML to be parsed by XSL, let the MobileFirst do it own parsing and send the result to me.

Example:

XML

```
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

My XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="/">


        <xsl:choose>

        <xsl:when test="count(*//catalog) != '0'"> 
               dosomething

        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
           i want to go back to normal mobilefirst way of converting XML to Json 
        </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>

</xsl:template>
```

My Question :

Is there a way to output normal XML file to MobileFist Adapter again so that the apapter's normal XML to JSON conversion is done. This I want to be done from Adaptername.xsl file ?

Comment: Can you please rephrase your text as a Question? What is the question?

Comment: I just want my XSL to work at some condition and rest of the time i want worklight to carry its own standard way of converting XML to JSON.

Comment: @IdanAdar as far as this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26973751/how-to-perform-xslt-transformation-for-input-request-in-adapter answer it is said that XML is converted to new XML which is not the case in Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

The XSL transformation cannot decide "on-the-fly" if to follow through with the transformation or not.

This will probably then require a second request from you.

1. Get the XML
2. Check if it contains the require node
3. Send another request but this time to a procedure that does the transformation

Comment: No according to your way , i want to get my XML data twice so that once i can check and once i can transform but that takes time and its not possible for me i have a large content of data

Comment: Please Check the stackoverflow Question and answer i have attacehed below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26973751/how-to-perform-xslt-transformation-for-input-request-in-adapter which is not a correct one i hope.

Comment: You should return what you need - not everything.

Comment: Say that my condition failed and now i want all the response XML to be converted to JSON and sent to the mobile i cant do that in this case right.